# Reading floating point values from a file drops all or part of the decimal part

Tags: c++, floating-point, fstream, ifstream

I need to read floating-point values from a file.

Basic sample code of how I do this:

```
int main() 
{
    float number;
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("testfile.dat");

    inputFile >> number;

    cout << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first line in the file is: 13212.13131. But when I cout 'number' the displayed number is: 13212.1

The problem is part of the decimal gets dropped and in other cases all of it gets dropped. Why does this happen, and how can I solve this problem?

The point of reading the number from the file is to do mathematical calculations with it.

Comment: Try to set appropriate stream [flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/)

Comment: Remember - the "precision" you see in cout is *NOT* necessarily the actual precision of the stored value. You can change the displayed precision using [ios_base::precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) or [std::setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).  Also: you might consider using double instead of float.

Comment: Six significant figures for a `float` is about right, isn't it?

Comment: And note that this is happening on *output,* not on input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, floating-point precision on output (for both `std::cout` and `printf`) is 6 decimal digits by default. You need [`std::setprecision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to get it print more digits. But you'll then get to the limit of `float` type.

On most systems float is [IEEE-754 single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), therefore it can only store about 7 digits of significant. The nearest to 13212.13131 is [1.3212130859375E4](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049051050049050046049051049051049). If you need more precision, you must use [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which has about 15-16 digits of precision on most systems.

Read more: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)

Comment: So if I'm understanding what you are saying correctly, The value stored in number is correct the problem arises when I want to cout the value?

Comment: yes. It's acccurate to the float's precision. Printing more digits will only introduce more garbage

Answer (score 1):

Try using `std::setprecision()`:

```
cout << setprecision(14) << number << endl;
```

You will need to

```
#include <iomanip>
```

If that doesn't solve it you should try debugging it and see what the number actually is (`13212.13131` or `13212.1`).

Comment: The output when I include setprecision() is: 13212.1309 which is still not correct. This also does not solve the problem if I were to do mathematical calculations with 'number'. I am a bit of a noob in c++, how do you debug?

Comment: @Craig For that see the `FLT_DIG` value defined in `float.h`, which should be 6. This is the precision (number of digits) of a `float`. If you need more precision, use a `double`.

Comment: Q: How do you debug?  A: That depends largely on your compiler, and your preferences.  Microsoft Visual C/C++ (Windows) and XCode (Mac) both have their own graphical debuggers.  For Linux, I use g++ (compiler) and gdb (debugger) - both command line.

Comment: a -1 for suggesting that `float` can store a number with 14 significant decimal digits. I don't know any system on which this is true. You're basically teaching the OP to misunderstand rendered output. In fact you don't answer the question at all, so another good reason to downvote :P